# Shell script which returns elapsed time, memory usage and CPU usage of executed script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I need to write a bash script which will be able to return elapsed time, RAM usage and CPU usage of executed script.

my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
STARTTIME=$(date +%s%N)

#here is script which needs to be executed

ENDTIME=$(date +%s%N)

echo Elapsed time: $(($(($ENDTIME - $STARTTIME))/1000000))ms
```

Elapsed time works, but how to do the rest?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the U&L stack exchange site! Please review the [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) to get information on how to best post on this site.To get to your question, where are you having the most trouble? What have you tried and what specifically does not work? [Please edit your post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/476581/edit) to include this additional context. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the `/usr/bin/time` (GNU `time`) and its supported formatting options that you could do something like:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f 'Elapsed time: %es\nMemory usage: %M KB\nCPU usage: %P' echo 'Hello World!'
Hello World!
Elapsed time: 0.02s
Memory usage: 672 KB
CPU usage: 57%
```

see `man time` for more formatting options.

Comment: please mention that that (GNU) `time` command will have to be explicitly installed; at least on debian and centos, it's not installed by default. (there is a `/usr/bin/time` on *bsd, but it doesn't support any formatting options).